# Module path order in virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, pythonpath

I noticed a strange phenomenon related to dist-packages paths. The order of my  paths in my system-wide installation of python 3 (simply running `python3` and then printing `sys.path`) is as follows:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

i.e. the path in `local` is preferred. However, creating a virtual environment and running `python3` after activating the environment gives:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
```

The order is clearly reversed. Yet, pip still searches local first, which results in a different version of a library seen by pip dependencies and a different one used when importing.

Can someone explain the discrepancy?

EDIT:

When the virtualenv is activated, the pip used is the one installed in the virtualenv:

```
pip 9.0.1 from ~/.virtualenv/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

and yet, despite the path pointing first to dist-utils in `/usr/lib`, it does resolve dependencies with what's in `/usr/local/lib`:

```
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in ./.virtualenv/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: appdirs>=1.4.0 in ./.virtualenv/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from setuptools)
Requirement already up-to-date: packaging>=16.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from setuptools)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.6.0 in ./.virtualenv/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from setuptools)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyparsing in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools)
```

Comment: how did you find out `pip` searches in `local` first?

Comment: where is pip you invoked? that is, what will "which pip" show?

Comment: I answered in the question. What's more interesting to me is why is the order of paths in sys.path inverted in the virtualenv? I would prefer Python to use /usr/local first, just like it does outside the virtualenv.

Comment: Interestingly, this problem does not occur for python 2, the paths are not switched, and always local is first, even in the virtualenv

Comment: The problem was related to old version of virtualenv in the system. Upgrading virtualenv resolved the problem.